# Browning of potted Tomato plants?

Tags: leaves, tomatoes

I have some Roma Tomatoes that I have just brought outside the last few days now that we have some warmer nights (50s) and hotter days (70s and 80s) to harden off.  I noticed this morning some light browning on the leaves and was wondering if this was anything I needed to worry about and/or if there was anything I could do about it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think it's just stress from the change. I've never seen it on direct seeded tomatoes. The leaves won't heal(which is why I don't think it's nutrient related - the white spots are dead) but the plant will grow fine.

Comment: I observed sth similar when pruning the growing tip. In my case, i think oedema caused this. The plant was pumping water up, but half of the plant was missing, therefore some of the cells popped. Don't worry, the new growth will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem with my Roma tomato plant. The yellow, uncurled leaves  can signal a nitrogen deficiency or it could also be a fungal infection.

You may wanna apply a nitrogen-rich organic vegetable fertilizer or a fungicide to see if this solves the problem. In my case, the fertilizer and regular watering did the trick. Btw, I use [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HHO110) fungicide on my other plants that were infected by either fungus or insects and it has worked great so far.

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestions on a good organic fertilizer?

Answer (score 1):

Those look pretty similar to spider mite damage.  Which I am currently battling (successfully) in Texas.  They bite individual cells and suck out the juices, leaving that stippling pattern.  I think a fungus would have larger diameter circles, and thrip damage is usually in squiggly lines, not dots.

Look very closely at 10-15 leaves undersides.  If there are very small bumps moving around slowly (mine look dark red but there are many different varieties), those are probably spider mites.  I squished many with my fingers.  Also I use the 3-in-1 Organicide concentrate spray during the early morning and wash it off before the sun hits the plants to prevent burning.  The mites thrive in very hot, dry weather.  Sometimes reproducing once every 3 days (the hotter the faster).